# Nginx Error log - uninitialized "logging" variable

Tags: nginx, logging

We are using this syntax in our nginx configuration:

```
 set $logging 1;

    if ( $bot_in_log = 0 ) {
    set $logging 0;
    }

    if ( $ip_in_log = 0 ) {
    set $logging 0;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$logging;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

However, we receive these messages in our error.log from bad bot requests:

```
24946#24946: *26106 using uninitialized "logging" variable while logging request, client: 122.34.124.134, server: domain.com, request: "GET /index.html/bwd0GoD HTTP/1.1"
```

Do we need to set `if=$logging;` for the error_log as well to avoid these kind of errors from showing up?

Comment: Maybe try to place `set $logging 1;` in more general scope to be always predefined.

Comment: good idea will try that